# Function or stored procedure that returns table which can be used using dynamic table names

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Right now I have a stored procedure that takes 2 table names (as `NVARCHAR`) and generates dynamic SQL to calculate some comparison statistics on the two tables, then uses `EXEC sp_executesql` to execute the dynamic SQL.

All this works great.

But I need a way to be able to use the generated table after the `EXEC dbo.stored_procedure_name`. I know this is not possible with a stored procedure and only functions can do that. But functions cannot use dynamic SQL.

So how can I do what I need? I basically need **something** that takes a few parameters, two of them being table names, and outputs a table that can be used downstream.

Here is an example of my stored procedure:

```
-- the stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_myTest 
    @t1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @t2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @row_count_t1 INT
    DECLARE @row_count_t2 INT
    DECLARE @row_count_difference INT

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- get # of rows in t1
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT @row_count_out = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @t1
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@row_count_out INT OUTPUT', @row_count_out = @row_count_t1 OUTPUT;

    -- get # of rows in t2
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT @row_count_out = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @t2
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@row_count_out INT OUTPUT', @row_count_out = @row_count_t2 OUTPUT;

    -- calculate difference
    SET @row_count_difference = @row_count_t1 - @row_count_t2

    -- print result
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT @row_count_t1 AS "' + @t1 + '", @row_count_t2 AS "' + @t2 + '", @row_count_difference AS "Row_Count_Difference"'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@row_count_t1 INT, @row_count_t2 INT, @row_count_difference INT', @row_count_t1 = @row_count_t1, @row_count_t2 = @row_count_t2, @row_count_difference = @row_count_difference
END
GO

-- usage
EXEC sp_myTest 'table1', 'table2'
```

Comment: Create a temp table or declare a table variable matching the proc result set schema and then insert the result set returned by the stored procedure using  [`INSERT...EXEC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

> But I need a way to be able to use the generated table after the EXEC dbo.stored_procedure_name

as I understood, you can save the data into a temp table (or real table)
as next :-

instead of last two lines:-

```
 SET @SQL = N'SELECT @row_count_t1 AS "' + @t1 + '", @row_count_t2 AS "' + @t2 + '", @row_count_difference AS "Row_Count_Difference"'
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@row_count_t1 INT, @row_count_t2 INT, @row_count_difference INT', @row_count_t1 = @row_count_t1, @row_count_t2 = @row_count_t2, @row_count_difference = @row_count_difference
```

Type the next lines:-

```
if exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'TblResult')
begin
    Drop table TblResult
    print 'TblResult table has been dropped'
end
-- print result
SET @SQL = N'SELECT @row_count_t1 AS "' + @t1 + '", @row_count_t2 AS "' + @t2 + '", @row_count_difference AS "Row_Count_Difference" into TblResult'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@row_count_t1 INT, @row_count_t2 INT, @row_count_difference INT', @row_count_t1 = @row_count_t1, @row_count_t2 = @row_count_t2, @row_count_difference = @row_count_difference

select * from TblResult
```

The **Fix** is:-

1. Use `INTO` clause for saving the data into `TblResult` table.
2. To set the procedures usable more once without getting any errors, the check if statmnet , for dropping the TblResult if existing.
3. You can use Temp Table rather than real table via adding `#` in the beginning of table name

Now your result is saved into TblResult table, use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE sp_myTest 
    @t1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @t2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

   SET @SQL = N'SELECT
                   (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM ' + @t1+') AS '+@t1+',
                    (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM ' + @t2+') AS '+@t1+',
                    ((SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM ' + @t1+') - (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM ' + @t2+')) AS row_count_difference;'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    END;
```